# If static means it doesn't need any objects, then how does java follow OOP?

Tags: java, oop, static

Without creating an object, I could use a variable in classes. How does this follow OOP concepts?  I am little bit confused.

```
public class NoObject {
    public final static String name="java";  //static variable
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
       String n = NoObject.name;  // with out creating of object i could use that variable here
       System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

*Output : java*

```
public class A {
   public static String a;

   public static void display() {
       a = NoObject.name;
       System.out.println(a);   
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(a);    
   }
}
```

*Output : java*

Comment: oops is abbreviation of what ?

Comment: Please edit your post to make it clear what you have problems with. Do you know what static does? Have you read the tutorials? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Answer (score 2):

All the static fields are held in a special class object which is associated with the class.  If you do a heap dump, you can see this special object.

So while you don't have an explicit object you reference in a static context, there is actually an object in the HotSpot/OpenJDK JVM. Similarly, when you have a `static synchronized` method in the class `MyClass` you are actually locking the `MyClass.class` object even though you don't mention it.

In short, actually, there is an object, but it is implicit in the language.

Note: if you have multiple class loaders, you can have a complete set of static fields for each class loader. i.e. you end up with multiple objects for holding the `static` fields.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in the sense that the presence of "static" can be seen as a violation of "pure object orientation". The inventors of Java regarded it as "acceptable compromise"; and we just have to live with that.

"static" can be really helpful sometimes; but especially when thinking about unit testing, unwise usage of "static" can turn into a night mare.